# Homotopy equivalence of wedge sums

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm trying to prove that if there is a (pointed) homotopy equivalence between $(X_k, x_k)$ and $(Y_k, y_k)$ for each $k = 1, \ldots, n$, then there is a (pointed) homotopy equivalence between $\bigvee_{k = 1}^n X_k$ and $\bigvee_{k = 1}^n X_k$ as a lemma to help with a homework problem, but I'm struggling and want to check that it's true before sinking too much time into it.

In case it is true, I'll include both my major attempts so far so maybe I can get past where I'm stuck.

I define the quotient map $\pi$ and injection maps $i_k$ for the $X$ spaces elsewhere in the problem.

My first attempt:
Third, we will show that if $(X_i, x_i) \simeq_\ast (Y_i, y_i)$ for each $i$, then $\bigvee_{i = 1}^n X_i \simeq_\ast \bigvee_{i = 1}^n Y_i$. Let $q: \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i \to \bigvee_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ be the quotient map, $f_k: (X_k, x_k) \to (Y_k, y_k)$ pointed homotopy equivalences, and $j_k: Y_k \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ the injection maps. Then $j_k \circ f_k: X_k \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ is a map. By the universal property of the disjoint union, there is a unique map $\tilde f: \coprod_{i = 1}^n X_i \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ such that $\tilde f \circ i_k = j_k \circ f_k$ for each $k$. Then $q \circ \tilde f: \coprod_{i = 1}^n X_i \to \bigvee_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ is a map. Further, for any $(x, k), (x', k') \in \coprod_{i = 1}^n X_i$, if $(x, k) \sim (x', k')$, then either $(x, k) = (x', k')$, or $x = x_k$ and $x' = x_{k'}$, in which case
$$\left(q \circ \tilde f\right)(x, k) = [(f_k(x_k), k)] = [(y_k, k)] = [(y_{k'}, k')] = [(f_{k'}(x_{k'}), k')] = \left(q \circ \tilde f\right)(x', k).$$
Then by the universal property of the quotient, there is a unique map $f: \bigvee_{i = 1}^n X_i \to \bigvee_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ such that $f \circ \pi = q \circ \tilde f$. Since $f_k$ is a pointed homotopy equivalence, there is a pointed homotopy inverse $g_k: (Y_k, y_k) \to (X_k, x_k)$ for each $k$, and there are similarly unique maps $\tilde g: \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n X_i, g: \bigvee_{i = 1}^n Y_i \to \bigvee_{i = 1}^n X_i$ such that $\tilde g \circ j_k = i_k \circ g_k$ for each $k$ and $g \circ q = \pi \circ \tilde g$. Then for each $k$,
\begin{gather*}
f \circ g \circ q \circ j_k = f \circ \pi \circ \tilde g \circ j_k = q \circ \tilde f \circ i_k \circ g_k = q \circ j_k \circ f_k \circ g_k \simeq_\ast q \circ j_k,\\
g \circ f \circ \pi \circ i_k = g \circ q \circ \tilde f \circ i_k = \pi \circ \tilde g \circ j_k \circ f_k = \pi \circ i_k \circ g_k \circ f_k \simeq_\ast \pi \circ i_k.
\end{gather*}

My second attempt:
Third, we will show that if $(X_i, x_i) \simeq_\ast (Y_i, y_i)$ for each $i$, then $\bigvee_{i = 1}^n X_i \simeq_\ast \bigvee_{i = 1}^n Y_i$. Let $q: \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i \to \bigvee_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ be the quotient map, $j_k: Y_k \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ the injection maps, $f_k: (X_k, x_k) \to (Y_k, y_k)$ pointed homotopy equivalences, and $g_k: (Y_k, y_k)$ their homotopy inverses. Then $j_k \circ f_k: X_k \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ is a map. By the universal property of the disjoint union, there is a unique map $\tilde f: \coprod_{i = 1}^n X_i \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ such that $\tilde f \circ i_k = j_k \circ f_k$ for each $k$. Similarly, for each $k$, there is a unique map $\tilde g: \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n X_i$ such that $\tilde g \circ j_k = i_k \circ g_k$. Then
\begin{gather*}
\tilde g \circ \tilde f \circ i_k = \tilde g \circ j_k \circ f_k = i_k \circ g_k \circ f_k \simeq_\ast i_k,\\
\tilde f \circ \tilde g \circ j_k = \tilde f \circ i_k \circ g_k = j_k \circ f_k \circ g_k \simeq_\ast j_k.
\end{gather*}
For each $k$, let $H_k: X_k \times I \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n X_i$ and $F_k: Y_k \times I \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ be pointed homotopies between $i_k$ and $\tilde g \circ \tilde f \circ i_k$ and between $j_k$ and $\tilde f \circ \tilde g \circ j_k$, respectively. For each $t \in I$, define $H_{k, t}: X_k \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n X_i$ by $H_{k, t}(x) = H_k(x, t)$ and $F_{k, t}: Y_k \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ by $F_{k, t}(y) = F_k(y, t)$, and note that $H_{k, t}, F_{k, t}$ are maps since each is the composition of a homotopy with an injection map $X \to X \times I$. Thus, again by the universal property of the disjoint union, for each $t \in I$ there are unique maps $H_t: \coprod_{i = 1}^n X_i \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n X_i$ and $F_t: \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ such that
$$H_t \circ i_k = H_{k, t} \quad \text{and} \quad F_t \circ j_k = F_{k, t}.$$
Define $H: \coprod_{i = 1}^n X_i \times I \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n X_i$ by $H((x, k), t) = H_t(x, k)$ and $F: \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i \times I \to \coprod_{i = 1}^n Y_i$ by $F((y, k), t) = F_t(y, k)$. Then
\begin{gather*}
H((x, k), 0) = H_0(x, k) = H_{k, 0}(x) = H_k(x, 0) = i_k(x) = (x, k),\\
H((x, k), 1) = H_1(x, k) = H_{k, 1}(x) = H_k(x, 1) = \left(\tilde g \circ \tilde f \circ i_k\right)(x) = \left(\tilde g \circ \tilde f\right)(x, k),\\
H((x_k, k), t) = H_t(x_k, k) = H_{k, t}(x_k) = H_k(x_k, t) = (x_k, k),
\end{gather*}
and
\begin{gather*}
F((y, k), 0) = F_0(y, k) = F_{k, 0}(y) = F_k(y, 0) = i_k(y) = (y, k),\\
F((y, k), 1) = F_1(y, k) = F_{k, 1}(y) = F_k(y, 1) = \left(\tilde g \circ \tilde f \circ i_k\right)(y) = \left(\tilde g \circ \tilde f\right)(y, k),\\
F((y_k, k), t) = F_t(y_k, k) = F_{k, t}(y_k) = F_k(y_k, t) = (y_k, k).
\end{gather*}

Comment: I think this is true. For $x$ in the wedge of $X$’s, define a new homotopy by $H_t(x) = H_t^i(x)$ for $x \in X_i$ where $H_t^i$ is the homotopy between $X_i$ and $Y_i$. Then this should give you a homotopy between the wedges I think.

Comment: That was my approach for a homotopy between the disjoint unions, but I'm not sure how to show a family of functions combine to make a continuous map

Comment: I think that does it for me! I was thinking about the pasting lemme but wasn't sure about using it for some reason; I think that the fact that I'd mostly used it when the restriction domains overlapped was throwing me off. I was hoping to prove the result for arbitrary pointed spaces, but the problem is about spaces where each $X_i$ has a neighborhood which deformation retracts onto the base point.

Comment: Okay great! What’s the general problem you’re trying to solve?

Comment: Isn’t that just equal one of the homotopies you start with which is continuous by assumption?

Comment: Not technically, but it is (I think) $H_k \circ (i_k \times \mathrm{id}_I)$, which is what I originally thought and just forgot when I went to type it up (forgive me, it's late). The problem is to prove that the fundamental group of the wedge sum is the free product of the fundamental groups of the summanda

Comment: Got it. Do you have Van Kampen’s theorem? If so, you can generalize the result in example 1.21 of the following: http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/MAT1300/Week%203%20Term%202.pdf

Comment: Oh, it needs the projection onto $X_k$ rather than $i_k$

Comment: Yes, that's the main result. I'm showing the result in discussion to verify that the fundamental groups of the neighborhoods in the wedge sum are isomorphic to those of the summands. I realise it's probably more general than I need, but it seemed like a useful result, and I anticipated it being easier to prove haha